# How to get List<String> inside of a POJO with MyBatis Mapper?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

My goal is to fill the `UserDto` POJO using the 'UsersMapper' MyBatis Mapper.

```
public class UserDto {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private List<String> authorities;

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities.stream()
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
}
```

```
@Mapper
public interface UsersMapper {
  @Select("SELECT users.username, users.password, role_authorities.authority " +
          "FROM users " +
          "JOIN role_members ON role_members.username = users.username " +
          "AND users.username=#{username} " +
          "JOIN role_authorities ON role_authorities.role_uuid = role_members.role_uuid")
  Optional<UserDto> getUsers(String username);
}
```

This is how it looks like if I run the SQL statement directly.
[image]

My expected result is: MyBatis successfully fill the `UserDto` POJO.

My actual result is I got an exception

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 3
```

Comment: See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-map-a-list-of-simple-type-objects-string-integer-etc-to-a-bean-or-map-).

Answer (score 0):

This POJO has a field which is of type `List`. `@Select` is not enough, you have two ways to solve this problem:

1. Add `@Results` declare all the fields that this query returns, then use `@Result`'s `many` attribute to link another subquery.
2. Via XML, use `<Collection>` tag in your 'ResultMap' XML tag.